# Table view not working

Tags: ios, uitableview

I get an error by the IBoutlet of tableView saying "cannot override with stored property "tableView"". I'm not quite sure what this means, any type of help will be appreciated. 
    import UIKit

```
class UsersViewController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var users = ["Marc", "Mark" , "Louise", "Ahinga", "Amossi", "Kalenga"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    override func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! userCell
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `UITableViewController` comes with a `UITableView` built in, aptly named `tableView`. In the code you pasted you are adding an extra `UITableView` to it and giving it the same name. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

In theory, when you are using a plain vanilla `UITableViewController` from the storyboard you should not link the table to an `IBOutlet`. That's taken care of.

If you are building something more sophisticated that needs an extra `UITableViewController` on top of the one that the class provides in storyboard, then you should name it differently.

Answer (score 1):

you have to set as it's `delegate` and `dataSource` in `viewDidLoad()` like this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't be the case. A `UITableViewController` complies, by default with the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocols, and its `tableView` is set to it.